# How to dynamically create div and adjust the div on change of checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am little stuck in my problem, the thing is i want to create a button on which a div of width 100% will get render, in every div or every row of div i will have a checkbox, on clicking box i will get the value of checkbox that is true or false.

Note :- This boolean value i will get on clicking checkboxes .

I am sharing my code too :-

```js
window.onload = function () {
  
  var arrayDiv = [];
  document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for(var i=0; i <= 1; i++){
        arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
        arrayDiv[i].id = 'block' + i;
        arrayDiv[i].className = 'block' + i;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(arrayDiv[0].appendChild(arrayDiv[1]));
  };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <style>
      div {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="newsectionbtn">New Section</button>
    <!-- <div id="container">
      <section id="mainsection">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mobile" checked=true  />
      </section>
    </div> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make an algorithm which will fulfill my conditions :-

so my usecase is :-

Here t represents true and f represents false :-

Assume here **isSectionTrue** is an array and it has boolean values of checkboxes that is checked or unchecked

```js
/*
 * isSectionTrue = [t,t,t]
 * div-1 100%
 * div-2 100%
 * div-3 100%
 *
 * isSectionTrue = [t,f,t]
 * div-1 50%
 * div-2 50%
 * div-3 100%
 *
 * isSectionTrue = [t,f,f]
 * div-1 33%
 * div-2 33%
 * div-3 33%
 *
 *
 * isSectionTrue = [f,t,t]
 * div-1 100%
 * div-2 100%
 * div-3 100%
 * 
 * isSectionTrue = [f,t,t,f,f,f,t,f,t]
 * div1 - 100%
 * div2 - 100%
 * div3 - 25%
 * div4 - 25%
 * div5 - 25%
 * div6 - 25%
 * div7 - 50%
 * div8 - 50%
 * div9 - 100%
 */
```

Comment: The only checkbox in the code provided is commented out so i'm not sure how they're involved in this. And I don't get how the values of isSectionTrue translate to the div width. Could you clarify or narrow down the problem?

Comment: i was trying to render checkbox with every div

Comment: thing is i want a button or checkbox or radio button on that boolean value will be decided so take checkbox as example and there are two divs if 1st div checkbox is true, 2nd checkbox is false then both div will get width 50% and will aligned in one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that:

```js
const arrayDiv = [];

document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = e =>
  {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    , chkBx  = document.createElement('input')
    ;
  newDiv.id         = 'block' + arrayDiv.push( newDiv )
  newDiv.className  = 'block' 
  chkBx.type        = 'checkbox' 
  chkBx.checked     = true
  chkBx.onclick     = checkBoxesSet
 
  document.body.appendChild( newDiv )
  newDiv.appendChild(chkBx)
  }

function checkBoxesSet()
  {
  let e1 = 0
    , cut = 1
    ;
  for (let i = 1; i< arrayDiv.length; ++i)
    {
    if (!arrayDiv[i].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked)
      cut++
    else
      {
      setDivWidth(cut, e1, i)
      cut = 1
      e1  = i
      }
    }
  setDivWidth(cut, e1, arrayDiv.length)
 
  function setDivWidth(cut, e1, eN)
    {
    let percent =  (100 / cut).toFixed(2)
    for( let n = e1; n < eN; ++n) arrayDiv[n].style = `width:${percent}%`;
    }
  }
```

```css
div {
  height     : 30px;
  width      : 100%;
  display    : inline-block;
  border     : 1px solid black;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  }
```

```html
<button id="newsectionbtn" >New Section</button>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start:

```js
const arrayDiv = [];

document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = e =>
  {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    , chkBx  = document.createElement('input')
    ;
  newDiv.id         = 'block' + arrayDiv.push( newDiv )
  chkBx.type        = 'checkbox' 
  chkBx.dataset.ref = newDiv.id 
  chkBx.onclick     = checkBxClick
 
  document.body.appendChild( newDiv )
  newDiv.appendChild(chkBx)
  }
  
function checkBxClick (e)
  {
  let chkBx = e.target
  console.clear()
  console.log( chkBx.dataset.ref, chkBx.checked )
  }
```

```css
div {
  height  : 50px;
  width   : 100%;
  display : flex;
  border  : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="newsectionbtn">New Section</button>
```

Comment: yes thats correct for phase 1, phase 2 is when the second div checkbox is true then its width should be 100 /2 i.e 50% and will get aligned in the first div row likewise if three div is there and 1st div is false and last 2 is true then no change but is this is the case [true,false,true] then 100 / 3 i.e 33.33% and last two will get aligned with first div row

Comment: @Ronak07 except that you don't indicate anything of your rule of thumb between the checkboxes and the dimensions. Give at least the formula to calculate that

Comment: formula we have implement it i have given the usecase above based on that usecase we have to generate the formula

Comment: the checkbox value (true and false) of each block will be pushed into array and according to that we have to satisfy the above usecase|
* isSectionTrue = [t,f,t]
 * div-1 50%
 * div-2 50%
 * div-3 100%

this it means div1 and div2 will aligned in single row taking width of 50% and 3rd div will be 100% this output will be based upon the true and false value of checkbox which will be in array

Comment: @Ronak07 it's empirical, it's not an algorithmic formula

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way.

```js
document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var contenedor = document.getElementById('container');
  var numBlock = contenedor.childElementCount + 1;
  div.id = 'block' + numBlock;
  div.className = 'block' + numBlock;
  div.innerHTML = `
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckb_block${numBlock}" checked />
  `;

  contenedor.appendChild(div);
};

document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').onclick = (e) => {
  //You can get the parent element like this
  //var parentElement = e.target.parentElement;
  //or
  var parentElement =       document.querySelector(`#${e.target.id.split('_')[1]}`);
  if(e.target.checked) {
    /* Do something */
  } else {
    /* Do something else */
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="newsectionbtn">New Section</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

When you check a div, you change the style or add a class to it. It depends on how you handle it,